# Blue background in StreamPlot output?

Tags: plotting, regions

In `12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)` writing:

```
A1 = Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}];
A2 = ImplicitRegion[{-3 <= x <= 3, -3 <= y <= 3}, {x, y}];

vector = {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2};

GraphicsGrid[{{StreamPlot[vector, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}],
               StreamPlot[vector, Element[{x, y}, A1]],
               StreamPlot[vector, Element[{x, y}, A2]]}}]
```

I get:

[image]

where it's evident that in two cases there's a blue background rectangle, easily erased with the mouse.

Is it possible to delete this background graphic with some command?

Comment: I don't see the blue rectangle in 11.0 or 12.0 on OSX.

Comment: @TeM: I also see the blue cover and am also running Windows 10, 64-bit.

Comment: This is a documented update. See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html#690893008. Set [`RegionFillingStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFillingStyle.html) and [`RegionBoundaryStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBoundaryStyle.html) to `None` to avoid it.

Comment: Another useful example: http://wolfram.com/xid/0tzjz4bm-ej8974

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a deliberate change in version 12.1. To recover the old behavior, do this:

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]],
           RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, RegionFillingStyle -> None]
```

As another example, compare the following three figures (picture omitted, so that you can try it out and see for yourself):

```
{Visualization`Core`StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]],
 StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]],
 StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[],
            RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, RegionFillingStyle -> None]}
```

Comment: @J. M.: I think there might be some syntax issues and I think I corrected them: ``{Visualization`Core`StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 
   1 + x - y^2}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]], 
 StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]], 
 StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 
  RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, RegionFillingStyle -> None]}``

Comment: @Moo, thanks. Copy-pasting from the cloud is sometimes a crapshoot.

Comment: Thanks for the fix to this annoying change.